# How to skip not completly empty rows in r

Tags: r, datatables, rows, skip

So, I'm trying to read a excel files. What happens is that some of the rows are empty for some of the columns but not for all of them. I want to skip all the rows that are not complete, i.e., that don't have information in all of the columns. For example:

[image]

In this case I would like to skip the lines 1,5,6,7,8 and so on.

Comment: Please post a reproducibe example. You can use `dput()`. For your problem you might want to read about  the function `complete.cases()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably more elegant way of doing it, but a possible solution is to count the number of elements per rows that are not `NA` and keep only rows with the number of elements equal to the number of columns.

Using this dummy example:

```r
df <-  data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:6],
                 B = c(sample(1:10,5),NA),
                 C = letters[1:6])

  A  B C
1 A  5 a
2 B  9 b
3 C  1 c
4 D  3 d
5 E  4 e
6 F NA f
```

Using `apply`, you can for each rows count the number of elements without `NA`:

```r
v <- apply(df,1, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))

[1] 3 3 3 3 3 2
```

And then, keep only rows with the number of elements equal to the number of columns (which correspond to complete rows):

```
df1 <- df[v == ncol(df),]

  A B C
1 A 5 a
2 B 9 b
3 C 1 c
4 D 3 d
5 E 4 e
```

Does it answer your question ?